# What are the standard method known to secure WCF services or web services in general?

Tags: wcf, web-services, security

What I am looking for is a set of article that can help me understand the basics, so I can be sure of what I am doing.

Methods regarding secure authentification are the most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [this article](http://killustar.blogspot.com/2009/03/secure-wcf-services-with-authentication.html) about Securing WCF Services with Authentication Service.
also [this](http://www.leastprivilege.com/CertificateBasedAuthenticationAndWCFMessageSecurity.aspx) one on Certificate based Authentication.

take a look at [Programming WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms731925.aspx) in msdn library